# Name of Southern California tree with a peeling bark?

Tags: identification, trees

What is the name of this Southern California tree which has a peeling bark? Have about 18 of these, all are the same kind with their outer bark being soft/spongy. I've attached some photos here too.

Bark of one of the tree
[image: 1st image]

Leaves of the tree
[image: 2nd image]

Another shot where outer bark was recently peeled out
[image: 3rd image]

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like a Cajeput Tree. It grows in southern California, has the "shedding" tree trunk, the leaf shape appears to be a match, (linear) as well as the color of the branches and shoots.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your tree is called Melaleuca quinquenervia. My particular trees, of the Melaleuca family, puts vanilla colored flowers that resemble a bottle brush and has pods of seeds as well. Your trees trunks and leaves look exactly like mine. And I just learned today from the other post that the common name of my trees is Cajeput Tree. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I know this tree as a Melaleuca which I first saw in Southern California, but recently found it in San Francisco in abundance.

Comment: Susan, if you have a new question (“would Melaleuca quinquenervia grow in Sonoma County”), please post it as such. Note that this is is a Q/A site, with a specific format unlike the standard web forums you may be familiar with. I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help], especially [ask], before posting a new question.